# libGL error: for steam

Tags: steam

I am trying to install steam after installing 15.04. When It should be installed the icon shows in my applications, but wont launch when i click on it. I entered

> steam<

in the terminal, and got this...

> Setting up Steam content in /home/brandon/.local/share/Steam
>   /home/brandon/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 475: no match: ssfn*
>   find: `/home/brandon/.steam/steam': No such file or directory
>   Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
>   STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
>   Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
>   libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
>   libGL error: driver pointer missing
>   libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
>   libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
>   libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>   <

I have tried to Remove it, to Purge it to Install it again. I dont know what is going on.
What should I do next?

Comment: What Drivers do you have installed. [edit] you post and add the output of `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`